# To show that $S^\circ = S \setminus \partial S$ in a topological space $T$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $S^\circ = S \setminus \partial S$ by a double inclusion argument. I have done one direction:

Take $x \in S^\circ$, then $x \in S$ and S is a neighbourhood of $x$. Suppose $x \in \partial S$, then for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ we have $U \cap S \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap (T\setminus S) \neq \emptyset$. But $S$ is a neighbourhood and clearly $S \cap (T\setminus S) = \emptyset$, contradiction, hence $x \in S \setminus \partial S$.

I can't seem to do the other inclusion, any guidance?

Comment: The symbol for interior is $\circ$, "\circ", not $0$. This is particularly confusing here as $S^0$ is standard notation for the $0$-sphere.

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S^c$ denote the complement of $S$ in $T$.

To prove $S \setminus \partial S \subseteq S^\circ$, it suffices to show the contrapositive, i.e.,

$$(S^\circ)^c = T \setminus S^\circ \subseteq T \setminus (S \setminus \partial S) = (S \setminus \partial S)^c = (S \cap (\partial S)^c)^c = S^c \cup \partial S.$$

Take $x \in (S^\circ)^c$. If $x \in S^c$ then we are done so assume that $x \in S$ and we will show that $x \in \partial S$. Let $U$ be any neighbourhood of $x$ in $T$. Then $U \cap S$ is a neighbourhood of $S$. If $U \cap S \subset S$ then $x \in S^\circ$ which is a contradiction. Thus $U \cap S$ meets $S^c$. Since $x \in S$, we cannot have $U \cap S \subseteq S^c$. Thus every open set containing $x$ meets both $S$ and it's complement. Then $x$ better be in the closure of $S$.

Comment: Surely $(S \cap (\partial S)^c)^c = S^c \cup \partial S$ not $S^c \cap \partial S$ by De Morgan?

Comment: That's right. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in S$. Then $x\in\partial S$ iff all neighbourhoods of $x$
meet the complement of $S$. So if $x\in S$ but $x\notin\partial S$
there's a neighbourhood of $x$ not meeting the complement of $S$...

Comment: Think I've finished this... $U \cap S = \emptyset$ is not possible since $x \in U, x \in S$. So $(U \cap (T \setminus S)) = \emptyset$ thus $U \setminus S = \emptyset$ hence $U = S$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in S^\circ$. Then there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $x \in U \subseteq S$. So $x \in S$. But alss $x \notin \partial S$, because if $x$ *were* in $\partial S$ any neighbourhood of $x$, so also $U$ would have to intersect $S$ and $S^c$ But $U \subset S$ so $U \cap S^c = \emptyset$, so $x \notin \partial S$, so $x \in S\setminus\partial S$. This is what you had too , essentially.

So suppose $x \in S \setminus \partial S$. in particular $x \in S$, and $x \notin \partial S$ means that there exist some neighbourhood of $U$ of $x$ such that either $U \cap S = \emptyset$ or $U \cap S^c = \emptyset$. The first alternative cannot hold, as $x \in U \cap S$ always. 
So we have some $x \in U$ a neighbourhood with $U \cap S^c  =\emptyset$. The latter means exactly that $x \in U \subseteq S$, and so $X \in S^\circ$ as required.

The easy facts we use are $$A \cap B = \emptyset \leftrightarrow A \subseteq B^c$$
and $$x \in \partial S \leftrightarrow \forall U \text{ open } : x \in U \to (U \cap S \neq \emptyset \land U \cap S^c \neq \emptyset)$$ which implies

$$ x\notin \partial S: \exists U \text{ open }: x \in U \land (U \cap S = \emptyset \lor U \cap S^c = \emptyset)$$ by simple logic